# A doubt about extended dislocation

Tags: band-structure, condensed-matter, physical-properties-of-materials, materials-engineering, metals

I wonder why this phenomenon occurs:

> "Unlike unextended screw dislocations, the extended screw dislocations
> define a specific slip plane, the {111} plane of the fault and it
> will be constrained to move in this plane."

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information. Where is this quote coming from? What have you done to figure it out? What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: Why are the atom planes situated above (111) pane and the ones situated below the (111) plane pulling each other?

Comment: +1 But I removed the second question because we have a policy to only allow one question per question, and also I agree with Cody that you should give a reference for where this quote came from.